# How to list all required npm peerDependencies

Tags: npm, peer-dependencies

How can I list out all currently required peer dependencies in my project?

I've tried searching, but I only find a bunch of custom packages to *check* peer dependencies. I already know they're currently ok, but I want a list of what packages and versions they actually are.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 11):

If searching by the name of a package then running the command below gives peer depdencies

```
npm info bootstrap peerDependencies
{ jquery: '1.9.1 - 3', 'popper.js': '^1.16.0' }
```

Running it on the entire package.json file is something I am not familiar with

Comment: Glad to share this command. thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with the following bash script started from your project folder. For ease of understandability it calls node for each matching package.json. To improve performance you can replace the multiple here documents by a single one (arround the for loop) and call node once.

```
#!/bin/bash
for d in $(find node_modules -name package.json \
           -exec grep -lw peerDependencies {} \;)
do
    node << EOF
        const {peerDependencies } = require('./$d');
        for (k in peerDependencies) {
            console.log('File $d:', k, peerDependencies[k]);
        }
EOF
done
```

And here the more performant version:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                      
for d in $(find node_modules -name package.json \                                
           -exec grep -lw peerDependencies {} \;)                                
do                                                                               
        echo "m = require('./$d');                                               
for (k in m.peerDependencies) {                                                  
    console.log('File $d:', k, m.peerDependencies[k]);                           
}"                                                                               
done |                                                                           
node
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-liner that depends on the `jq` utility.

```
jq ".dependencies,.devDependencies | keys | flatten[]" package.json | xargs -t -I {} npm info {} peerDependencies
```

This will pull the keys from the `dependencies` and `devDependencies` objects of your `package.json` then pipe those keys to `npm info`, printing the generated command at each step.